# Is it possible to make a guessing game with Python, where is each input will receive random number, like dynamic looping input?

Tags: python, random

For example I wanna input a random number and if it will be wrong then next input generate a new random number and so on..

Here is my code, but this is not what i want

```
import random 

secret_number = random.randint(0, 10)
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 20 

while guess_count < guess_limit: 
    guess = int(input('Guess between [0, 10]: ')) 
    guess_count += 1    
    if guess == secret_number: 
        print('You won!') 
        break
else: 
    print('Wrong..')
```

Comment: You're very close. You just need to include the line `secret_number = ...` again. Can you figure out where? Also, looks like your indentation is off

Comment: For the indentation issues see language editors: Jupyter, Komodo, PyCharm.

Comment: Thnak you very much, it works !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Sure!

You're very close, but you're not using python 3 syntax correctly (assuming you're using python 3, because that's what it looks close to).

You should rethink your looping architecture, in my opinion. Typically, a 'While' loop is used when the number of iterations is dynamic. Because your number of attempts is static, you can simply use an 'if' loop. In python, you can specify this using a range loop.

Try something like this (on the latest version of python 3!):

```
import random

num_guesses = 20

print("I'm thinking of a new number between 1 and 10...")
secret_number = random.randint(1, 10)

    for x in range(0, num_guesses):
        try:
          user_guess = int(input(f"What's your guess? You have {num_guesses - x} tries left."))
        except:
          print("Invalid Number, skipping guess!")
          continue
        if (user_guess == secret_number):
            print("Congratulations, you won!")
            exit(0)
    print("Sorry, you lost. Try again!")
```

If the user wins, the game quits, as it should. You will only hit the loss case if you go through all 20 iterations and the user never wins.

Though, I would recommend either making the range of random numbers bigger than the number of guesses, or generating a new number each time...

```
for x in range(0, num_guesses):
    print("I'm thinking of a new number between 1 and 10...")
    secret_number = random.randint(1, 10)
    user_guess = input(f"What's your guess? You have {num_guesses - x} tries left.")
```

With 20 guesses, and a static number between 1 and 10, it's impossible to ever lose! You should also include the try, except block in case someone doesn't enter a number. (Can't trust your users!)

(EDIT: Fixed a couple of issues. Wasn't casting ints correctly for matching, and created the possibility of generating a 0, turning the shell into a liar. Added error catching too. Enjoy!)